# Change all entries in a column when 1st 9 digits match the 1st 9 digits from another sheet

Tags: find

In Sheet 1 col X is my master list starting row 11 with unique 9 digit refs

```
   A-1/10000 TEXT FOLLOWS
   A-1/10001 TEXT FOLLOWS
   A-1/10002 TEXT FOLLOWS
   A-1/10003 TEXT FOLLOW
```

I have a stored list in (col C in sheet 2) starting row 11 with text preceded by 9 digit ref

eg
A-1/10000 TEXT FOLLOWS
A-1/10001 TEXT FOLLOWS
A-1/10000 TEXT FOLLOWS
A-1/10002 TEXT FOLLOWS
A-1/10000 TEXT FOLLOWS
A-1/10003 TEXT FOLLOWS
A-1/10000 TEXT FOLLOWS

If any text is changed in sheet 1 Col X , How can I get ALL entries in sheet 2
starting with same 9 digits to change  to  have same text as Sheet 1 Col C.

I tried some VBA (copied) and it worked apart from it only changed the text in
the first entry found  with 9 digits to match. All other entries remained the same
and I can,t find a workaround.